# How do you target multiple ancestor classes in LESS

Tags: css, less

How to produce the CSS underneath given the following HTML?

HTML

```
<body class="foo bar">
    <div>Content</div>
</body>
```

LESS (?)

```
div{
    .foo & .bar &{
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

CSS DESIRED RESULT

```
.foo.bar div{
    // Stuff
}
```

Comment: If you want `.foo.bar div`, then how about writing `.foo.bar div`? What is it about your problem that you think constitutes "targeting multiple ancestor classes"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` symbol simply inserts that parent selector at that position:

```
div{
    .foo.bar &{
        // Stuff
    }
}
```